# text is not responsive when width is set

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a text that I need to set a width on. This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjenjms3/) I have marked the text with red. The column needs to fill the half of the columns. But everytime I set a width, the responsive does not work anymore.

**The reason the layout is in tables, is because I have to use them for email newsletters. So I am using the foundation framework**

How can a set a width on the column with the red text, without destroyin the responsive part?

```
<body>
      <table class="body">
        <tr>
          <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
            <center>
                <table class="row footer">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">


                            <table align="center" class="container">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    <table class="row">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
                                            <table>
                                              <tr>
                                                <th style="color:red;">Details about the room</th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </th>

                                          <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
                                            <table>
                                              <tr>
                                                <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lectus fringilla optio nulla dolorem duis, augue neque mus gravida, platea pharetra duis eros nunc eget. Integer facilis. A convallis nec libero leo tempus, facilisis ac, fringilla at quis, lectus inceptos ac eu suscipit. Porta ac dignissim nec, cursus aliquam senectus aliquam, in duis vestibulum at risus libero volutpat, mi aliquam, tristique sit nunc fermentum</th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: And view css style ?

Comment: Where's the CSS.. Also, why on earth are you using tables?!

Comment: Fiddle is too long, reduce it to what it's really needed

Comment: Thank you for the comments. As I am writing in my question, I am making a newsletter. Therefore I am forced to use tables. There is 750 CSS lines, so I made a fiddle in my question aswell. But I just uploaded the example here: http://vouzalis.com/test.html

Comment: Yes I can see the fiddle is very long. The problem is that it is the framework for foundation, so if I delete anything the framework is not working.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://www.useloom.com/share/c825c5e0e7be11e69309454fac1abeab

Comment: Yes that is excact that what I am trying to do. The problem is that Outlook 2010 and 2013 is so quickly messing things up. Did you set a width of 50%?

Answer (score 0):

I have set the first and the last `th` width of `50%`. The it works If I got your question right. You've to divide the row into two with half width of the total.

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/mjenjms3/1)